# Slick2D KeyListener doesn't get input

Tags: java, slick2d

I wanted to add a custom keylistener to my Slick2D input system, thats what i've done:

```
    KeyListener a = new Keyboard(this);
    c.getInput().addKeyListener(a); // c = GameContainer
```

And this is my keylistener class:

```
public class Keyboard implements KeyListener {

    private CreppyMole instance;

    public Keyboard(CreppyMole instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void inputEnded() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void inputStarted() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAcceptingInput() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setInput(Input arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(int arg0, char arg1) {
        System.out.println("Yes");

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(int arg0, char arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

When I press any key, the system doesn't print anything, while it should print "Yes".
What is wrong there? I've added the keylistener, should work?

Answer (score 1):

Solved, basically you need to enable accepting input by doing this:

```
@Override
public boolean isAcceptingInput() {
    return true;
}
```

Slick2D will access isAccpetingInput, if it returns yes, it will use the class as the input.